# Laravel Nova - How to determine the view (index, detail, form) you are in for a resource's computed field?

Tags: laravel-nova, computed-field

I would like to return a different result for a computed field when viewing the index view than when viewing the detail view of a resource.

Basically something like viewIs() below:

```
Text::make('Preview', function () {
    if($this->viewIs('index'){
        return \small_preview($this->image);
    }
    return \large_preview($this->image);
 })->asHtml(),
```

Answer (score 9):

You can check the class of the request:

```php
Text::make('Preview', function () use ($request) {
    if ($request instanceof \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ResourceDetailRequest) {
        return \large_preview($this->image);
    }

    return \small_preview($this->image);
});
```

Otherwise, you can create your own viewIs function:

```php
// app/Nova/Resource.php

/**
 * Check the current view.
 *
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @retrun bool
 */
public function viewIs($view, $request)
{
    $class = '\Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\\Resource'.ucfirst($view).'Request';

    return $request instanceof $class;
}
```

Then you can do it like this:

```php
Text::make('Preview', function () use ($request) {
    if ($this->viewIs('detail', $request) {
        return \large_preview($this->image);
    }

    return \small_preview($this->image);
});
```

Comment: This technique appears to no longer be reliable in v4

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, @Chin's answer did not work for me as for Edit view the request class is just a basic `Laravel\Nova\Http\Request` class.

My workaround to check if this is an index view is as follows:

```
/**
 * Check if the current view is an index view.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest $request
 * @return bool
 */
public function isIndex($request)
{
    return $request->resourceId === null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NovaRequest` class will soon be able to help, as the `isResourceIndexRequest` and `isResourceDetailRequest` are already in master.

As the Nova repo is private I will keep you posted, when it will be usable.

In the meantime I am falling back to helper methods on the Nova Resource class (`app/Nova/Resource.php`):

```php
namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ResourceDetailRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ResourceIndexRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Resource as NovaResource;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;

abstract class Resource extends NovaResource
{
    // [...]

    /**
     * Determine if this request is a resource index request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isResourceIndexRequest($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof ResourceIndexRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if this request is a resource detail request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isResourceDetailRequest($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof ResourceDetailRequest;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    $fields = [
        // [...]
    ];

    if ($this->isResourceDetailRequest($request)) {
        if ($this->isResourceDetailRequest($request)) {
            $fields = array_merge($fields, [
                // [...]
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this little helper class

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class CurrentResourceAction {
    public static function isIndex($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ResourceIndexRequest;
    }
    public static function isDetail($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ResourceDetailRequest;
    }
    public static function isCreate($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest &&
            $request->editMode === 'create';
    }
    public static function isUpdate($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest &&
            $request->editMode === 'update';
    }
}
```

you can call it anywhere you need to

Comment: How do I instantiate $request in Nova Resource class?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but hey! You can check against the `NovaRequest` properties `editing` and `editMode` ('create', 'update', 'attach' etc.)

```php
// Determine if you are creating a model. 
$request->editMode == 'create';
```

Or as they say, "Read the source Luke" and see how they determine it. See the  `Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest`, it contains similar checks.

```php
namespace Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests;

class NovaRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if this request is via a many to many relationship.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function viaManyToMany();

    /**
     * Determine if this request is an attach or create request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCreateOrAttachRequest();

    /**
     * Determine if this request is an update or update-attached request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest();

    /**
     * Determine if this request is a resource index request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isResourceIndexRequest();

    /**
     * Determine if this request is a resource detail request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isResourceDetailRequest();

    /**
     * Determine if this request is an action request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActionRequest();
}
```

Would've been nice if you can type hint the `NovaRequest` instead of the regular one in the Nova resource `fields()` method but it is not allowed due to the parent resource being extended.

Comment: In the latest Laravel Nova release - `v4`,  the `NovaRequest` is type hinted in the `fields()` and other methods so you can directly use these methods now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate fields for index & details page.

```
// ----- For Index page
Text::make('Preview', function () {
    return \small_preview($this->image);
})
->onlyOnIndex()
->asHtml(),

// ----- For Detail page
Text::make('Preview', function () {
    return \large_preview($this->image);
})
->onlyOnDetail()
->asHtml(),
```